# How to call a method when ever one field value is change in SQL Database?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am wondering if there is any provision in c# ASP.NET like: when ever `status` column in Database was changed I'd like to call a method.

Suggest me some ideas except call the database for every 1 minute or 1 sec something like. And you can suggest me is there any chances to do this from SQL, jQuery.

Comment: user **Sql Trigger**

Comment: You can use sql trigger on update.

Comment: If i use SQL Trigger in Server side how would i know that was changed. I need to again call to Server whether that field changed or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Service Broker` in SQL Server to receive notification in C#. Basically it adds the information in the queue which is read by the C# Code.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/21/sql-server-intorduction-to-service-broker-and-sample-script/

Another way is to use `SQL table dependency`

https://dzone.com/articles/receive-notifications-with-new-values-when-table-r